# why my span is not in middle of main container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display Booking in the middle of red screen but it fails, Main container must have to be `display:block` property however I can make changes to child div and span, I was able to make it work with margin-top set programmatically with position relative but that is causing some serious issues so I can't use margin top here, **i prefer to make it work with verticle-align:middle and text-align:center here**

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs-bottom">
    <div id="tab-1"> <span>Booking</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs-bottom {     // this can't change
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    background:red;
}
#tab-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVnR5/46/

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning or the below code.

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#tab-1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to just change the tabs display to `block`.

```
#tab-1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
#tab-1 {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

#tab-1 span {
    display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

> Since you said you can alter the child `display` Property i have made some adjustments in child div's CSS

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVnR5/47/)

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align: middle;` will only work with the `line-height` property set on the parent. So just change `height` to `line-height`.

```
.tabs-bottom {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 255px;
    background:red;
    text-align: center;
}
#tab-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 changes in `#tab-1` css:

**1.)** Use `line-height` to make vertical middle.  
**2.)** change `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` for horizontal middle.

like following:

```
#tab-1 {
    display: block;
    line-height: 255px;
    text-align: center;
   }
```

Check Your updated [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vVnR5/52/)

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help you

try it out

```
.tabs-bottom {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    background:red;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#tab-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8.5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe just remove `display: inline-block;`

```
.tabs-bottom {
display:block;
width: 100%;
height: 255px;
background:red;
}
#tab-1 {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/kmu3bov4/

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS positioning [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/vVnR5/54/)

```
.tabs-bottom {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    background:red;
    position: relative;
}
#tab-1 {
      position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-div{ height:300px; background:red }

.verticle-middle{ 
position:relative; 
top:50%; 
transform:perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
<div class="verticle-middle">
Verticle middle text
</div>
</div>
```